# How do you associate a custom id with a username

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have ID generation already but I need help saving that ID to a username.
Here's the generation code:

```
function makeId(){
   var text = " ";
   var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz023456789";
   for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
     return text;
}
```

It generates an ID with some of these characters and it just returns the ID, and I want to use this to address a user on my discord server

Comment: Every discord user has an id already. Why would you want to create one?

Comment: well i have a idea for profiles for my bot so people can address a fight with the shorter id (5 character id) generated so they dont have to go to dev mode to get someone elses id to fight them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `user.mention` or `user.username + user.discriminator` if you don't want to use mentions. Like this:

```js
var dictionary = new Object();

function store(user) {
  dictionary[user.username + user.discriminator] = user;
}
```

If you are okay with base64, you can use:

```js
var dictionary = new Object();

function addID(user){
   dictionary[Buffer.from(user.id.toString(16), 'hex').toString('base64')] = user;
}
```

If base32 floats your boat:

```js
var dictionary = new Object();

function addID(user){
   dictionary[user.id.toString(32)] = user;
}
```

If you just want to generate your own, making a random one will not work, because the same ID could possibly be assigned to multiple users. If you just want the code to save your generated ID's in a database, try:

```js
var dictionary = new Object();

function addID(user, myID){
  dictionary[myID] = user;
}

function retrieveID(myID) {
  return dictionary[myID];
}
```

If you are trying to save them in a file, use **JSON**.

> I hope I was able to help!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help, @GamersGotPower! :)

Answer (score 0):

user.id is read only. You would be able to wreak havoc if you could change user ids.

If you just want a different ID to reference a user with then you could create a dictionary where the key = random id and the value = the user object. But I don't know why you would want that.

Comment: thank you and yes i understand if i could change ids then i could wreak havoc but i need the id for a profile so yes i could use a dictionary and then im going to use that id when people are going to use the command gb-fight

Comment: if your user @mentions another user in a message there is a property in the message object that contains a collection of mentioned user objects.

message.mentions.users

This would get you a reference to both user objects.

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions